# How to show comment posted instantly after submitting

Tags: php, mysql

I am using ISSET condition to add comment on the page after saving it to database.

```
if (ISSET($_POST['comment_submit'])) {

    $comment_author = $_POST['comment_author'];
    $comment_content = $_POST['comment_content'];
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

    if ($comment_content!="") {
        $new_comment = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (post_id, comment_author, comment_content, comment_date) VALUES ('$post_id', '$comment_author','$comment_content', now())");
    }
}
```

but after redirecting to same page its not showing comment posted recently.
On **refersh** it starts displaying.

Comment: `isset()` should be in lowercase I think. How are you redirecting after the insert?

Comment: @jammypeach `isset()` is not case sensitive.

Comment: Just as a note, you're wide open to SQL injection attacks, http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php, and the mysql_* functions are depreciated, you should look at mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: @Daan yes you're right, just read up on that. Interesting... I don't think I've used a language that had case insensitive functions before. Every day is a learning day :)

Comment: Can you just save comment BEFORE selecting comment list from database? This way new comment will be saved and after that you get comment list with your new comment so user can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your code of fetching data from the database after the Insert Query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting the user to same page, you won't get values in $_POST variable, since the form is not submitted again. 
You may have to store comment_author and comment_content values in session or you may have to  pass these values while refreshing the page.

Comment: It looks like he/she is inserting the comment into the database in the first instance, so it's irrelevant if the $_POST global isn't populated on the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you're using pure php only.

- first thing you must do is to have a query that list down the available comments inside your db.
- second is posting your data and saving it.
- third, redirect your page to the comment section you're viewing.. use

header("Location: url")